# List small files in a directory and output a summary total

Tags: bash, awk

I want to (1)identify files in a directory that are under 64 bytes and (2)print out their names and size. The following one-liner does the job:

`find . -size -64c -exec ls -lh {} \;|awk '{print $5, $9}'`

This prints out a list of files, along with their size.
Can I easily extend this one-liner to also print out the total number of files found. In effect to pipe the file list into a `wc -l` command?

Comment: Consider not involving `ls` and `awk` in your existing command and instead just printing the file size in bytes and name directly with `find . -size -64c -printf '%s %p\n'`.

Comment: Could this non-awk one liner be extended to also print out the total number of matches?

Comment: No, to do that you'd have to pipe it to awk (or just `wc -l`) but it'd be much more efficient and could be easily tweaked to handle file names that include any characters, including newlines. I added an answer showing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider doing this instead:

```
find . -size -64c -printf '%s %p\n' | awk '1; END{print NR}'
```

That'd mean you're not spawning a subshell to call `ls` on every file found so it'd be much more efficient and could be easily tweaked to handle file names that include any characters, including newlines, e.g. with GNU tools to allow `NUL` separating the file names:

```
find . -size -64c -printf '%s %p\0' | awk -v RS='\0' '1; END{print NR}'
```

Add `-v ORS='\0'` if you want the awk output to be NUL-separated too.

If you don't want to do that, at least change:

```
find . -size -64c -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

to:

```
find . -size -64c -exec ls -lh {} +
```

so `ls` is called on groups of files instead of one at a time.

Note that as @dawg mentions in the comments `-printf` may be GNU-only.

Comment: I think the `printf` primary is unique to GNU version of `find`

Comment: @dawg could be, I've noted that now, thanks.

Comment: When you only want to count the number of files, you can use `-printf ".\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I easily extend this one-liner to also print out the total number
> of files found.

Yes, by printing `NR` at the `END` block:

```
... | awk '{ print $5, $9 } END { print NR }'
```

You can also include a suffix:

```
... END { print "Total number of files found: " NR }'
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems very easy to do with awk. I must read up on BEGIN/END statements.

Comment: @mikey : This breaks if one of the filenames contains a newline character or a space, because a newline is the default record separator in awk and the space is the default field separator.

Comment: @user1934428 Even though your comment is valid, it's also important to note that OP's original code will break in the same ways.

Comment: All my files are generated by a Python script that pre-processes them to give a file name with no spaces or special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a short Python script as well with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) to replace the `find` and the `awk`:

```
python3 -c 'from pathlib import Path
cnt, fsum=0,0
for fn in (x for x in Path().glob("**/*") if x.is_file() and x.stat().st_size<64):
    size=fn.stat().st_size
    print(f"{str(fn)}: {size:,} bytes")
    fsum+=size
    cnt+=1
    
print(f"Total files: {cnt:,} Total bytes: {fsum:,}")'
```

Some key elements:

1. An empty argument to `Path()` refers to the local directory `.` You could also use `Path(".")` to use the current directory. You could also specify a specific path there as the root of the file tree.
2. The glob `glob("**/*")` is a recursive directory walk for all files in or below the one specified by `Path` -- similar to `find`

Or in `ruby`:

```
ruby -e '
fsum=0; cnt=0
Dir.glob("**/*").each{|fn| 
    st=File.stat(fn)
    if (st.size<64 && st.file?)
        puts "#{fn}: #{st.size} bytes" 
        cnt+=1
        fsum+=st.size
    end
}
puts "Total files: #{cnt} Total bytes: #{fsum}"'
```